# Cómo resolver el problema de Matriz y Reinas

Tags: java

Estoy creando una matriz que representa un tablero de ajedrez cualquiera, y tengo dos reinas que tengo que colocar aleatoria mente en cualquier punto de la matriz, pero no pueden estar en la misma casilla, llevo tiempo.

Por ahora lo único claro que tengo es la matriz y que tengo que añadir la clase random, gracias de antemano

```
import java.util.Random;

class JavaApplication3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dim_x = 8;
        int dim_y = 8;
       char [][] matriz_car = new char [dim_x][dim_y];
```

Comment: Y dónde estás intentando usar random para elegir la posición?

Comment: a partir de aqui en las siguientes lineas tenia pensado usar la clase random para elegir un punto aleatorio en el vector "x" y otro en el "y" pero no se como hacer para que no se encuentren en el mismo punto nunca.

Comment: Ya te dieron una respuesta que puede que no cubra todos los casos pero da una idea. Como consejo, no tengas miedo de probar y que te salgan 309209384 errores. Escribe el código como lo has pensado, prueba y permítete fallar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuación una posible solución para tu duda, tomando en cuenta que son solo 2 reinas las que se desean colocar aleatoriamente:

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int dim_x = 8;
        int dim_y = 8;
        char[][] matriz_car = new char[dim_x][dim_y];

        // INFORMACION REINA 1
        char queen1 = 'R';
        int queen1PositionX = random.nextInt(8);
        int queen1PositionY = random.nextInt(8);
        matriz_car[queen1PositionX][queen1PositionY] = queen1;

        // INFORMACION REINA 2
        char queen2 = 'Q';
        int queen2PositionX = random.nextInt(8);
        int queen2PositionY = random.nextInt(8);

        //VERIFICA SI AL MENOS UNA POSICION NO SE REPITA PARA QUE SE ESTABLEZCA EN ESA POSICION
        while (queen1PositionX == queen2PositionX || queen1PositionY == queen2PositionY) {
            queen2PositionX = random.nextInt(8);
            queen2PositionY = random.nextInt(8);
        }
        matriz_car[queen2PositionX][queen2PositionY] = queen2;

        // IMPRESION DE LA MATRIZ
        for (char[] t : matriz_car) {
            for (char j : t) {
                System.out.print(j + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso se imprimiría de la siguiente manera dependiendo de los números aleatorios que se generen y sin repetir las posiciones:

```
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , Q,  ,
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
 ,  , R,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
```

Comment: Validas si no están en la misma posición pero no haces nada si eso pasa :)

Comment: Ya está validada esa parte, gracias por la observación